# How to record local and remote streams in a video conference using WebRTC - Laravel?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-recording, video-conferencing

I am currently on a Laravel project that can 1:1 or 1:8 video & chatting. The video conferencing is works perfectly using WebRTC, now I want to record the `audio only` of the entire conference.

I tried `MediaStreamRecorder` but it only record the local audio.

```
var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({
    url: turnserver,
    localVideoEl: 'localVideo',
    remoteVideosEl: '', // I created custom remoteVideos
    nick: {
      // stuffs
    },
    autoRequestMedia: true,
});
```

And lastly, I want to save it my server via AJAX.

Cheers

Comment: Using `RecordRTC` is only recording local, it can't record both local and remote.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I also want to achieve the same!!